# Daily temperature, GDP growth, population growth for Long Island (New York) during 2015-2022

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I need to predict the daily peak electricity demand for Long Island during 2015-2022. I found the weather forecast data ([here](http://mis.nyiso.com/public/P-7Alist.htm)). I also looked at [this](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets), but I could not find the temperature data for the Long Island. Also, I do not know how to extract other data from [here](https://www.economy.com/products/data) and [here](https://www.census.gov/data.html). I would greatly appreciate it if you could let me know how to have access to the daily temperature, GDP growth, and population growth data for the Long Island zone during 2015-2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your temperature data. You'll need to use a location that is close to your region of interest.
https://www.weather.gov/wrh/climate?wfo=okx

For the GDP, as far as I know, the smallest geography available is at county and metro level so, again, you'll need to use a region that is representative of your area of interest. I suggest you determine a geography that best fits your area and try to stick with that for all your data in order to be consistent. Since you can find quite a bit of data by county, maybe use Nassau County for the GDP and Population?

GDP data comes from the Bureau of Economic Analysis (BEA) here: https://www.bea.gov/data/gdp/gdp-county-metro-and-other-areas

FRED (the St Louis Federal reserve) has the BEA GDP here, that is sometimes easier to digest: Metro area data here: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/NGMP35620 and for the county here https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/REALGDPALL36059

And finally, population growth would come from the Census Bureau, as you know. Estimates are not yet available for 2022, but you can get growth through 2021 data from here:
https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/data/tables.2021.List_58029271.html#list-tab-List_58029271

Happy data wrangling!